# How to calculate frequency in speaker-microphone scenario like this?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, acoustics, frequency, interference, wavelength

We have a speaker and microphone, distance between them is 10 meters. They are both on 1 meter distance from sound-reflecting wall. Velocity of voice is 340 m/s. It is observed that microphone does not register certain voice frequencies. What is the lowest frequency that microphone does not register?

If I understood the above problem correctly, scenario should look like this:

[image]

I understand that if I knew the wawelenght, frequency could easily be calculated. However, we only have velocity of voice. Any advise on problem?

Edit: Found the solution by myself:

$(2*1m)^2 + 10m^2 = 103.9$

$sqrt(103.9) = 10.198$

$\Delta$$s = 10.198m - 10m = 0.198m = 0.5\lambda$

$f = c / \lambda = 340/(2*0.198) = 859Hz$

By the way, asking out of curiosity: why do you have "homework and exercises" tag if it's considered off-topic? Closing the question and leaving it unanswered doesn't support learning.